# Calcular coordenadas de plantilla pdf para sobrescribirla

Tags: php

Tengo la plantilla de Factura de AFIP y quiero saber como puedo obtener las coordenadas dentro del pdf, para asi, escribir los datos en el lugar correcto.
Adjunto imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Osea trabajo con FPDF y debo setear las coordenadas donde escribir cada dato.

Comment: No conozco FPDF, pero por mi experiencia con otras librerias (sobretodo iTextSharp) el eje del documento está en la esquina inferior izquierda y utilizan una medida que tiene en cuenta la _resolucion_ del documento (habitualmente en ppp o dpi, puntos por pulgada). En la documentación de tu libreria deberia estar esta información y sino prueba y error e ir ajustando.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurrio fue abrirlo con foxit reader y para el cursor en la posicion deseada, y mostrando la regla se ve perfecto el punto deseado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con acrobat reader podes ubicar las cordenadas de un archivo en distintos formatos

en Ver > Mostar/Ocultar > Reglas y cuadriculas > reglas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en estos formatos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]